# How to register app in "Open in" dialog in iOS if the app is built using react-native?

Tags: ios, react-native

The simple app is built using React Native. How to register it in "Open with" dialog? (For example, to allow user "open in" this app any webpage from Safari)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do that on the normal XCode/iOS side of things, there's no support within React Native specifically to do that.

Hopefully [this guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1587/_index.html) can get you started.